# Hibernate: How do i map an one-to-many association with a complex set of objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, associations, one-to-many, pojo

I have a DB model where there are two tables in a one-to-many association. For example purposes i will call them BALL and BASKET, even if it doesn't make much sense.

A basket can hold many balls and a ball can be in just one basket.

In the domain model i have a Ball class, a simple class with getters and setters, and i have a Basket class. I have also a "BallGroup" class, that is a strategy pattern implementation for retrieving balls.

```
  public class Ball {

    // getter and setters.
  }

  public interface IBallGroup {

    List getBalls(String type);
  }

  public class BallGroupStrategyA {

    private List balls;

    List getBalls(String type) {
        // StrategyA impl.
    }
  }

  public class BallGroupStrategyB {

    private Tree balls;

    List getBalls(String type) {
        // StrategyB impl.
    }
  }

  public class Basket {

    // How do i map the balls collection in this attribute?
    private IBallGroup ballGroup;
  }
```

The collection of balls is really stored in a IBallGroup object, but i don't have and don't need a "BallGroup" table in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can do the relationship like this(Bidirectional relation):

Class Basket{

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Ball.class,
orphanRemoval = true,cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="id_ball")
public Set<Ball> getBall() {
    return ball;
}
public void setBall(Set<Ball> ball) {
    this.ball = ball;
}
}
```

Class Ball:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_basket", nullable=false)
public Transportista getBasket() {
    return basket;
}
public void setBasket(Basket basket) {
    this.basket = basket;
}
```